# npm install does not install all the dependencies when executed from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab-ci

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/included:12.3.0 AS base-image

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN npm ci
CMD [""]
```

It gets built in Gitlab CI and in the next stage, this is executed as a script in the built image:

```
npx cypress run
```

Which fails due to missing dependencies, but when I do

```
npm install
npx cypress run
```

Everything seems to run fine, I want to include the npm install in the dockerfile and not execute it as a script.

Comment: I have also tried `RUN npm install` in the dockerfile, doesn't help

Comment: you must share your pipeline file because is not easy to guess what are you trying to do. Also, if you want to run that command you must run it in the dockerfile or in a container launched with the image you built ...

Comment: I built this image via kaniko and then run it as a container in the next stage, and then when I execute npx cypress run it gives error on some dependencies missing (which are there in the package.json file) but when I execute npm install within the same container it  seems to work.